# Implementation and generics like MyIterator<Entry<Key,Value>>

Tags: java, generics

I want to write this

```
    private final class OpenAddressingHashIterator<Entry<Key,Value>> 
implements Iterator<Entry<Key,Value>> {
}
```

But i can't and i don't understand why :(
But this work:

```
    public class OpenAddressingHashMap<Key,Value> extends
AbstractMap<Key,Value> implements Map<Key,Value>
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

abstract class OpenAddressingHashIterator<Key,Value> 
   implements Iterator<Entry<Key,Value>> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we can't use real type to define new type using generics. So in OpenAddressingHashIterator> Entry will be simple word, not concrete type(not Map.Entry), and in Iterator> we get error, because compile don't any know about type Entry, because type will set up in runtime. And one more moment, when we use this construction OpenAddressingHashIterator implements Iterator>, like specify @jas, we implement Iterator interface, but which already using type Map.Entry. Map.Entry generic type, and we can write Map.Entry. So Iterator> gives method signature with returning type/argument function Entry. But Map.Entry in Iterator get their Key and Value while runtime.